I want to push an image to ECR, and get scan Findings, and fail build if Critical vulnerabilities found
Recently, AWS made a change delegating ECR scan findings to the AWS Inspector. That change broke our CI/CD pipeline which builds our docker images.

After significant pain, I got to this script, which hopefully works and may help others.  The idea is to have the CI/CD push the new docker image (repo name + tag).  The code then checks the scan status with aws ecr describe-image-scan-findings, which may fail early because the scan has not started yet, and the image cannot be found in inspector. aws inspector2 list-findings will give a list of findings, or an empty findings array. In the non-empty case, a small json structure is returned indicating the counts of each severity type listed in the findings.
String scanFindings(String repositoryName, String imageTag) {
  withCredentials([[$class         : 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                    credentialsId    : 'aws-nca',
                    accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                    secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
    def findingsSummary = sh(script: """
      REGION="us-east-2"
      while true; do
          SCAN_STATUS=\$(aws ecr describe-image-scan-findings \\
                        --repository-name ${repositoryName} \\
                        --region \$REGION \\
                        --query 'imageScanStatus.status' \\
                        --output text \\
                        --image-id imageTag=${imageTag} || echo "ERROR")
          if [ "\$SCAN_STATUS" = "ERROR" ] || [ -z "\$SCAN_STATUS" ] || [ "\$SCAN_STATUS" = "PENDING" ]; then
              sleep 10
              continue
          elif [ "\$SCAN_STATUS" = "COMPLETE" ]; then
              break
          elif [ "\$SCAN_STATUS" = "FAILED" ]; then
              echo "Scan has failed."
              exit 1
          fi
      done

      FINDINGS=\$(aws inspector2 list-findings --region \$REGION \\
          --filter '{
              "ecrImageTags": [
                  {
                      "comparison": "EQUALS",
                      "value": "'${imageTag}'"
                  }
              ],
              "ecrImageRepositoryName": [
                  {
                      "comparison": "EQUALS",
                      "value": "'${repositoryName}'"
                  }
              ]
          }' \\
          --output json)
      FINDINGS_COUNT=\$(echo \$FINDINGS | jq -r '.findings | length')
      if [ "\$FINDINGS_COUNT" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "\$FINDINGS" | jq -Rs '. | fromjson | reduce .findings[] as \$item ({}; .[\$item.severity] += 1) | .'
      else
        echo "{}"
      fi
    """, returnStdout: true).trim()
    return findingsSummary
  } // with credentials
}

